# How to sign out?

Tags: support, user-interface, login

Sorry if this question is really nooby, I'm just not sure how to sign out of blender stack exchange. Any ideas?

Much appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before on the main meta: [How to log out of a Stack Exchange site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222556/278094)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over Blender big logo on the left, you can see StackExchange logo, with a little grey triangle on it's right side. Click the logo.There you'll find log out to click on.[image]

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: The original answer no long holds for either Chrome, or most mobile browsers, and possibly others.  Currently, the logout button is in the menu on the right side of the topbar:

[image: location of logout button]

Comment: Damn, I had to look around for this too. Now that I think of it, I don't think I have ever intentionally logged out of this site. I may have become addicted.